# How to add `parse_mode` to `sendMediaGroup`?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

## Edit 2

Answered [here](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/discussions/1791#discussioncomment-4839575),

```
[
    {
        media: "file_id1",
        type: "photo",
        caption: "**My caption\\!**",
        parse_mode: "MarkdownV2",
    },
    ...
]
```

---

## Edit 1

For now, I am making use of `editMessageCaption`, but it's not the cleanest solution.

---

Suppose the following,

```
const mediaGroup = [
  {
    media: 'file_id1',
    type: 'photo',
    caption: '**My caption!**'
  },
  {
    media: 'file_id2',
    type: 'photo',
  },
  {
    media: 'file_id3',
    type: 'photo',
  }
]

await bot.telegram.sendMediaGroup(123456, mediaGroup, {});
```

The caption is sent, but it isn't parsed as bold text. How can I pass on `parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2'` with this approach? `sendMediaGroup` doesn't accept this parameter.

Comment: You can't. `sendMediaGroup` doesn't accept a `parse_mode`.

Comment: @0stone0 Received [an answer](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/discussions/1791#discussioncomment-4839575) for this problem.